# PCIe link is not up?

Tags: pci-express

I have purchased a P4080 PCIe board from freescale which is in PCIe form factor. According to the documentation, if I connect the device into the motherboard PCIe slot and then turn it on after PC has booted up, looking at it's output from serial port should tell you that it was able to detect the PCIe link, but for me it gives me below message:

```
PCICSRBAR @ 0xff000000
PCI reg:0 0000000c00000000:0000000000000000 0000000020000000 00000000
PCI reg:1 0000000ffe000000:00000000ff000000 0000000001000000 00000100
PCIE Link is NOT up
PCIE Link only 1 lanes detected
Recycling PCIE Links, Retry limit 12
PCIE Link is NOT up
PCIE Link only 1 lanes detected
Recycling PCIE Links, Retry limit 11
PCIE Link is NOT up
PCIE Link only 1 lanes detected
Recycling PCIE Links, Retry limit 10
PCIE Link is NOT up
PCIE Link only 1 lanes detected
Recycling PCIE Links, Retry limit 9
```

And so on. The board seems to be okey on an older PC ( which has been produced in 2008 ). What are the possible problems here? The board is 8x and my motherboard slot is 16x.

Comment: Maybe your OS doesn't support PCIe hotplug?

Comment: It shouldn't be the case. They've tested the system on ubuntu 10.04 and I have the same version. Could it be something related to hardware?

Comment: I believe Ubuntu requires the `pciehp` (or `acpiphp`) module to be loaded. What does the host kernel say? Have you tried forcing a rescan? (`echo 1 > /sys/bus/pcie/rescan`)

Comment: Something I wanna mention, in this phase the host doesn't need to detect any PCIe. The board has a specific kernel module that needs to be inserted into the host to enable communication. In this phase the board boots up and would detect if there is any PCIe link is up or not. So I think anything on the host side shouldn't be important. I also did sudo "modprobe pciehp pciehp_force=1", but no difference happened out there.

Comment: the other issue is the board is somehow old and you cannot find so much about it in the forums. So i'm suspicious that from hardware perspective it's not compatible with new computers.